# Does the tensor bundle of a compact manifold have a bounded geometry?

Tags: riemannian-geometry

Let $M$ be a compact manifold. Let $S^2 T^*M $ be the vector bundle of all symmetric $(0,2)$ tensors and $S_+^2 T^*M$ be the open subset of all  positive definite ones. Does $S_+^2 T^*M $ have bounded geometry? It is understood that the metric on it is the tensor product of the induced metric on the cotangent bundle from some Riemannian metric on $M$.

Comment: see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/212713/do-cotangent-bundles-have-bounded-geometry/212723#comment527405_212723

Comment: @Kaveh   May you more explain on the structure of the metric on the bundle?

Comment: I read http://mathoverflow.net/questions/212713/do-cotangent-bundles-have-bounded-geometry/212723#comment527405_212723.  But I can not see the conclusion. $ s_+^2T^*M$ is a subbundle of $T^*M \otimes T^*M$, so the question is that is finite tensor product of cotangent bundle has bounded geometry.

Comment: About Riemannian metric, I think the natural metric is the tensor product of a Riemannian metric on the cotangent bundle. I dont not know yet what kind of metrics exist on cotangent bundles.

Comment: in the referred post $TM$ was considered with two types of metrics: Sasaki with flat fibers - not bounded geometry, and Cheeger-Gromoll, coming from submersion $GM \to TM$ of bounded geometry. So, the choice is yours.

Comment: see also http://mathoverflow.net/q/94322/1441

Comment: so it seems to me that the question is that does Cheeger-Gromoll induces, by pairing, a metric to the cotangent bundle with bounded geometry. Or is there a metric unrelated to the metrics on tangent bundle  which has a bounded geometry.

Comment: Kaveh - if I understand your pairing correctly, two Cheeger-Gromoll $T^*M pair T^*M$ is unbounded. But every open manifold which is finite handle-body - like any bundle over compact $M$ with fibres vector spaces; has a metric of bounded geometry. May be even invariant under the structure group action. The point is - to have fibers look like a cylinder - check the original Cheeger-Gromoll example.

Comment: Thanks valeri, I just need to know about the existence of a metric on the fiber bundle $S^2_+T^*M$ that has a bounded geometry. By what you said there is such a metric. Can you give me any some references about that argment.

Comment: @Kaveh -  I am not sure to whom this result was attributed (you may check referred posts), but to construct bounded metric on a finite handle body - take such metrics on handles and (accurately) glue them together (then average over the action of the structure group) - smth like this.  To construct handle decomposition you may consider (the non-degenerate deformation of) the distance to the zero section as a Morse function.

Comment: @valeri- many thanks, I think I am getting the answer.

Comment: @Kaveh - welcome!